# Why does npm install dependency package out of it's folder

Tags: npm, nodes, node-modules

when I run **npm install** all of the dependencies will not load in their own folder but instead install them in my node_modules folder so I end up with 50 or so folders. Is there a way to get dependency packages node_modules to stay within that dependencies folder?

[image]

Comment: This is a feature; it helps dedupe packages and avoids too-long paths.

Comment: @SLaks do you know if you can turn this feature off?

Comment: @AndyMac I don't think there is a way to turn it off in npm v3, but you can jump back to npm v2 which adheres to the nested model of dependencies.